# Get list of functions from eval

Tags: javascript, eval, jscript, wsh

#### Background

I have a `JScript` script running under `WSH`.

In my code I use `eval()` function. The string passed to `eval()` is essentially another piece of code to be executed. I expected this code to define function of a specific name. say `func()`

#### Question

How do I know whether the expected defined function indeed exists and callable after the `eval()` call.

#### Effort 1 - Failed

```
function isFuncCallable() {
    for (var m in this)
        if (typeof this[m] == "function" && this[m] == 'func')
            return true;

    return false;
}

eval("function func() { WScript.Echo(\"func was called\") }");
if (isFuncCallable())
    func();
else
    WScript.Echo("func is not callable");
```

`isFuncCallable` does not work as I expect it to work. It return false but if I call `func()` is would be a valid call.

---

## Update 1

As suggested

this works

```
function isFuncCallable() {
    for (var m in this)
        if (typeof  this[m] == "function" && m == 'func')
            return true;

    return false;
}

eval("function func() { WScript.Echo(\"func was called\") }");
if (isFuncCallable())
    func();
else
    WScript.Echo("func is not callable");

}
```

while this doesn't:

```
function Main() {
    function isFuncCallable() {
        for (var m in this)
            if (typeof this[m] == "function" && m == 'func')
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    eval("function func() { WScript.Echo(\"func was called\") }");
    if (isFuncCallable())
        func();
    else
        WScript.Echo("func is not callable");

}
Main();
```

Comment: What about running it and catching the error if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @conio this is what I'm doing at the moment. But, if exception is thrown, how can I make sure it is because `func` wasn't defined?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `this[m]`.

```
if (typeof this[m] == "function" && this[m] == 'func')
```

should be

```
if (typeof this[m] == "function" && m == 'func')
```

instead, because `for (x in y)` iterates through each element of y - you're thinking about using the `for (x = 0; x < y.length; x++)` style syntax.

Comment: 10x. but Still getting `func is not callable`. Question remains. How to iterate?

Comment: got it: edited, to use this[m] for the `typeof` constraint. That works in my browser console, anyway :)

Comment: yes. this work but look at my edit. weird case doesn't work

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked for me (though I'm using a browser and not WSH, so no WScript.Echo)

Comment: @moopet: Which browser? I replaced the two instances of "WScript.Echo" with "console.log" and run it in Chrome 54 DevTools. Doesn't work.

Comment: @conio Chrome 52.0.2743.116, Mac.

Comment: @moopet: I just tried with Chrome on Mac too (albeit 54 and not 52). [Doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg5pE.png). Are you sure you tried the version OP says doesn't work? The one where the code is inside the `Main` function?

Comment: @conio Here's a screenie of my console - https://moopet.net/40284383.png

Comment: @moopet: I don't know what's going on, but I tried it on Safari and Firefox (and Chrome canary) console and it didn't work. doesn't work on [repl.it](https://repl.it/EKAn) or [coderpad](https://coderpad.io/3KMD3MQG) either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for reference here is a solution:

```js
// b.js
// use IIFE to return an object with all exported functions and data

(function() {
    return {
       sum: function(a, b) { return a + b; }
    };
})();
```

now in another file

```js
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var b = eval(fso.OpenTextFile('b.js',1).ReadAll());

WScript.Echo(b.sum(3, 4));

for(var p in b)
{
    WScript.Echo(p);
}

// the output should be
// 7
// sum
```